# Ping resolve a IP but reply from a different IP

Tags: domain-name-system, ping

I'm try to ping a host name and it resolve to a IP(1.82.184.10).
But it does ping a strange IP(1.0.229.138)
What the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`1.0.229.138` is a router on the way from you to `1.82.184.10`. It informs you that it cannot reach the host (`1.82.184.10`) to deliver your ICMP packet. Most probably the host is down.

BTW, `ping` is not a tool to look up IP adresses, use `nslookup` for this.

Comment: NO.  1.82.184.10 is not down.

Comment: Then, it is filtered and 1.0.229.138 is a firewall.